# Get coordinates of every point in mouse movements

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I need ***all*** mouse movement coordinates: as the mouse moves, I need a continuous sequence of (x,y) values.  My current code leaves gaps:

```
def paint(self, event):
    self.line_width = self.choose_size_button.get()
    paint_color = 'white' if self.eraser_on else self.color

    coord = (event.x, event.y)
    if self.old_x == None or self.old_y == None:

    else:

        print(coord)
        paint_color = self.color
        self.c.create_line(self.old_x, self.old_y, event.x, event.y,
                                width=self.line_width, fill=paint_color,
                                capstyle=ROUND, smooth=TRUE, splinesteps=36)
```

`coord` is incomplete: it "jumps" some points, maybe because the mouse moves too fast and so it lost some points.  How can I record all of the points in transit?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995499/generating-pixel-values-of-line-connecting-2-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't record input with any finer grain than the sampling rate of the device.  If you're already set up for fine-grained events on mouse movements, that's the best you can do in that respect.

However, if you need contiguous points for some reason, you *can* interpolate the missing points to make a connected path.  The simple way is to connect the dots with [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm).  I recommend that you use something to smooth the curve; there are several packages that will fit a nice curve to a sequence of points; look for the term "spline" as well.